# How to kill session on browser tab or browser close?

Tags: javascript, session

We will destroy the session using js.

```
//--------- Code-----------------

<script>

window.onunload = function () {

$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout");

}

</script>

//------------ Code end----------
```

`window.onunload` function will send a call to the server for logout on the tab or browser close.

Comment: What's wrong with this code ? what is the issue ? Can you [edit] your post to add all details ?

Comment: @Elikill58 there is nothing wrong in this code, but I just want to know is there any another way for the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is pretty unstable, as you can also kill the browser without executing any JS

Comment: As Nico said, it's not stable. If it works, with not so much code, it's fine and I don't know how we could upgrade it instead of removing it when joining a page instead of leaving one